# pathFor cannot find route - Iron Router & Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes, iron-router

Iron Router cannot find a path that I'm pretty sure is defined correctly. The path name shows up as valid and exists in my meteor shell, but it returns as "undefined" in my Chrome console. Here's the template declaration:

```
<template name="vidPreview">
<div class="videoPreview">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <a href="{{pathFor route='singleVideo' _id=this._id }}">Play</a>
    <p>Created At: {{createdAt}}</p>
    {{#if isLive}}
        <p>LIVE</p>
    {{/if}}
    <p>Viewers: {{uniqueViewers}}</p>
    <p>Views: {{views}}</p>
    <p>Location: {{location}}</p>
    <ul>
        {{#each genres}}
            <li><p>{{this}}</p></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <p>Created by: {{creator}}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

And here's the route declaration:

```
Router.route('/video/:_id',{
  name: 'singleVideo',
  template: 'singleVideo',
  layoutTemplate: 'singleVideo',
  data: function(){
    var currentVideo = this.params._id;
    return Videos.findOne({ _id: currentVideo });
  },
  action: function(){
    this.render('singleVideo');
  }
});
```

There are no helpers operating on the vidPreview template. The data context is that of an individual Video object, and this template gets placed multiple times into a parent template. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you define the route? Are you sure it's available on client side?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the route name parameter in `pathFor` was positional, i.e.

```
{{pathFor 'singleVideo' _id=this._id }}
```

Answer (score 0):

["We can pass data, query and hash options to the pathFor helper."](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/)

Try:

```
{{pathFor route='singleVideo' data={ _id: this._id} }}
```